# В чем будет принципиальная разница при использовании NSInteger и NSUInteger?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, obj

Мне известно что просто integer (int) это целочисленное значение, однако с NSUInteger не сталкивался. Был бы рад если бы помогли разобраться и привели пример.

Comment: `u` - `unsigned` - беззнаковый тип

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

unsigned - означает "беззнаковый", т.е. не может иметь значения меньше нуля.

На более производительных платформах (например десктоп) используется long/ulong, в менее производительных (айфон) - int/uint

Comment: Каким образом поставленный код даёт ответ на заданный вопрос? Возможно, стоит добавить поясняющий текст. Ответы из одного кода обычно малопонятны участникам, особенно на таком уровне как у ТС.

Comment: unsigned - означает "беззнаковый", т.е. не может иметь значения меньше нуля. На более производительных платформах (например десктоп) используется long/ulong, в менее производительных (айфон) - int/uint